# Wordpress hook after theme is deleted

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I create theme in wordpress and now i create some theme options page in appearance.
Now if user remove theme from system i want to delete any data from database.

```
function register_my_setting() {
    register_setting( 'settings_grup', 'array_post_redirect');
} 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_setting' );
```

Now i want to delete options but only solution i found is hook: switch_theme and unregister_setting function. Is there any better hook to perform this ?

```
function un_register_my_setting() {
    unregister_setting ( 'settings_grup', 'array_post_redirect');
} 
add_action( 'switch_theme', 'un_register_my_setting' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good tutorial [here](http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/activationdeactivation-hook-for-wordpress-theme/#.VLEo9ivF_Hk) that shows you how to create a `register_deactivation_hook` for your theme. Wordpress does not have this feature for themes (like plugins) by default, but with a little tweaking your can duplicate the behavior for your theme.

For reference, it used to be done like this (pre 3.1 I believe):

```
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == "themes.php" ) { 
     // do your stuff 
}
```

Comment: ok if i use after_switch_theme and unregister_setting. Theme is still in choice of using and can be activated. But data is not(no trace in database), so it must be reconfigured ? correct ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly (and you correctly remove all the data), then yes, it should require reconfiguration.